# keras on R No accuracy enhancement or loss reduction during epochs

Tags: r, keras

my model doesn´t improve at all over the epochs and I can´t figure out why.

First of all, this is my model:

```
model <- keras_model_sequential() %>%
layer_dense(units = 16, activation = "relu", input_shape = c(1218)) %>%
layer_dense(units = 16, activation = "relu") %>%
layer_dense(units = 1, activation = "sigmoid")

model %>% compile(
optimizer = "rmsprop",
loss = "binary_crossentropy",
metrics = c("accuracy")
)

model %>% compile(
optimizer = optimizer_rmsprop(lr = 0.001),
loss = "binary_crossentropy",
metrics = c("accuracy")
)

model %>% compile(
optimizer = "rmsprop",
loss = "binary_crossentropy",
metrics = c("accuracy")
)

history <- model %>% fit(
x_train,
y_train,
epochs = 7,
batch_size = 500,
validation_data = list(x_test, y_test)
)
```

The Inputs look like this:

[x_train](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmSDu.png)

with this structure:

```
num [1:3500, 1:1218] 71567 73437 69071 71610 67758 ...

    attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
    ..$ : chr [1:3500] "14" "15" "16" "17" ...
..$ : NULL
```

and

[y_train](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONzg8.png)

with this structure:

```
num [1:3500] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
```

x_test and y_test have the same format and this is what I get from every epoch:

```
loss: 14.5759 - acc: 0.0857 - val_loss: 5.6937 - val_acc: 0.6429
```

These figures never change and I have absolutely no idea why. I hope someone can help me with this.

Comment: You need to normalize your input data.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Even when the data in x_train is normalized into just ones and zeros the same thing happens. Do you have any Idea why that could be?